# Inquiry: How to Pass My JSON object from my first script to the second one?

Tags: javascript, html, json, jquery, servlets

I have two javascript I have mostly finished writing except for one part. I am trying to figure out how to pass the JSON response from the servlet to a second javascript file.

I have an html that asks a user for some information. It passes this to the server and then returns the response as a JSON file. I have an html file that can display that information as needed, but it is in a second javascript. So I need to figure out how to pass it from the ajax method in my first javascript to my second javascript.

After that is done, I have programmed the web portal to provide the user a link to click on and they can see the second webpage.

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/getData',
            data: dataString, 
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(result)
            {

                            //Pass Result to Second JavaScript File
                            //Should this be a POST method or 
                            //Window? 
                            alert(success);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                alert("Error: " + textStatus + " exception: " + errorThrown);
            }

        });
```

The second javascript file is finished, and has been tested on a local json file on the hardrive. I just need to figure out how it can accept the json info passed to it from the first file?

```
$.getJSON('WhatGoesHere?', function(data)
{
    //Parsing happens in here and works. 
});
```

I hope folks don't downvote this. There is plenty of +rep I am prepared to give and I really did implement the rest myself. It is just this part I am stuck on. I read all this stuff about windows and post/get stuff, but I am really confused myself on this last part. I can't decide which is better to implement here? I am thinking maybe a post to json file and then doing a get to that because they both live on a server and eventually I will implement the json as a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/getData',
    data: dataString,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (result) {

        $(document).trigger("data_was_gotten", result);
        alert(success);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Error: " + textStatus + " exception: " + errorThrown);
    }

});

$(document).on("data_was_gotten", function(evt, data) {
    //do stuff with data
})
```

Comment: nope, you are triggering the event to the scope you care about.
check out: [jquery on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [jquery trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Comment: In the example I posted, I am triggering the event "data_was_gotten" within the scope of document and I am listening for the event within the scope of document.

Comment: This is a promising start. I was trying to save the information as a local json file. I don't want to have to learn php just do do that.

Comment: Unfortunately, the data in the second javascript is know undefined. Still reading. :(

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect that when the "on" listener fires on the event "data_was_gotten" there are two arguments.

Comment: That worked. Do you have any additional documentation on why I would need the event to work? Thanks for your help. +Rep for you. Literally.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am going to abandon this approach. Not working for my needs. I need a way to store this data so that when I open up my second html file, it can read the second javascript, which can read that JSON. I might look at PHP.